# flask render_template passed variable not being used in the template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm currently working on a project and I'm having a problem with flask and render_template. When I pass a variable into render_template, it doesn't actually pass through to the template. I've already tried putting the string into a variable and a few other things but nothing has worked so far.

Here's the function I'm returning:

```
return render_template("sell.html", error="Invalid Ticker")
```

Here's "sell.html":

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Sell{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Sell a Stock!</h1>
    {% if error is defined %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{error}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if success is defined %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{success}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/sell" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticker">Ticker:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ticker" name="ticker">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="buynum">Shares:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sellnum" name="sellnum">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sell</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the render_template function it is working fine. The problem is `error is defined` doesn't exists in jinja2.

just try a simpler html example to test:

```
{% block title %}Sell{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<p> {{error}} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

so change :

```
{% if error is defined %}

and 

{% if success is defined %}
```

to

```
{% if error %}

{% if sucess %}
```